# Django admin emails are not sending properly

Tags: python, django, email

I'm not sure why my error logging is not working.  When I try to log an error with a logger that has the default 'mail_admins' handler, no email is sent even though SERVER_EMAIL and ADMINS appear to be properly defined.  Looking in the postfix logs, I get this line whenever I try to send one of these emails:

```
Nov 20 11:55:58 localhost postfix/smtpd[1027]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <g>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<no-reply@mydomain.com
> to=<g> proto=ESMTP helo=<localhost>
```

Why would it be trying to send the email to 'g' rather than the specified admin email?

Edit: By the way, send_mail does work correctly.

Comment: It's trying to send the message to `g`, and being rejected because that address doesn't exist. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with postfix so I've removed that tag.

Comment: Thanks, I parsed that log line incorrectly.  Any django people have any ideas why it would be trying to send an email to "g" rather than the admin email I specified?  Here's the ADMIN assignment from settings.py:

ADMINS = (
    ('John Doe','some_email@that-isnt-just-g.com')
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ADMINS = ( ('John Doe','some_email@that-isnt-just-g.com') )
```

Should be:

```
ADMINS = [ ('John Doe','some_email@that-isnt-just-g.com') ]
```

Or:

```
ADMINS = ( ('John Doe','some_email@that-isnt-just-g.com'), )
```